# NestJS dependency issue

Tags: javascript, typescript, dependency-injection, nestjs

NestJS can't resolve dependencies of my service,
The error says that :  Nest can't resolve dependencies of the AuthService (?, JwtService, ConfigService, +, EventEmitter, +, MailerService, MessageService). Please make sure that the argument dependency at index [0] is available in the AuthModule context.

app.module.ts

```
@Module({
  imports: [
    ConfigModule.forRoot({
      envFilePath: [`.env.stage.${process.env.STAGE}`],
      validationSchema: envValidationSchema,
    }),
    TypeOrmModule.forRootAsync({
      imports: [ConfigModule],
      inject: [ConfigService],
      useFactory: async (configService: ConfigService) => ({
        type: 'postgres',
        autoLoadEntities: true,
        entities: [__dirname + '/**/*.entity{.ts,.js}'],
        synchronize: true,
        host: configService.get('DB_HOST'),
        port: configService.get('DB_PORT'),
        username: configService.get('DB_USERNAME'),
        password: configService.get('DB_PASSWORD'),
        database: configService.get('DB_DATABASE'),
      }),
    }),
    AuthModule,
    MessageModule,
    EventEmitterModule.forRoot(),
  ],
  providers: [
    {
      provide: APP_GUARD,
      useClass: ATGuard,
    },
    {
      provide: APP_GUARD,
      useClass: ActiveUserGuard,
    },
  ],
})
export class AppModule {}
```

auth.module.ts

```
@Module({
  imports: [
    ConfigModule,
    TypeOrmModule.forFeature([User, Device, VerificationCode]),
    JwtModule.register({}),
    forwardRef(() => MessageModule),
  ],
  controllers: [AuthController, UsersController, DevicesController],
  providers: [
    AuthService,
    UserRepository,
    UsersService,
    ATStrategy,
    RTStrategy,
    DevicesService,
    VerificationCodesService,
  ],
  exports: [UsersService, AuthService, UserRepository],
})
export class AuthModule {}
```

users.service.ts:

```
@Injectable()
export class UsersService {
  constructor(
    private repo: UserRepository,
    private readonly config: ConfigService,
  ) {}
}
```

auth.service.ts:

```
export class AuthService {
  constructor(
    private usersService: UsersService,
    private jwtService: JwtService,
    private config: ConfigService,
    private deviceService: DevicesService,
    private eventEmitter: EventEmitter2,
    private verificationCodesService: VerificationCodesService,
    private mailerService: MailerService,
    @Inject(forwardRef(() => MessageService))
    private messageService: MessageService,
  ) {}
}
```

As you can see nest can't inject UsersService to AuthService, Also the DevicesService and VerificationCodeService are shown as + in the error message. Both of them are inside the Auth module.

Any idea?

Comment: There's probably a circular import path somewhere between your `AuthService` and `UserService` (not necessarily a circular dependency between the classes, but a circular import chain of files). Can you provide access to the code, or a reproduction without any private code, so we can help track down the import that's causing the issue?